# A linear combination of the set $\{ {\bf A},{\bf A}^T\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, finite-fields

Consider $\mathbf{A}$, an $n \times n$ matrix over $\mathbb{F}_q$, the finite field with $q$ elements. The transpose of $\mathbf{A}$ is denoted with $\mathbf{A}^T$.
Let $\mathbf{I}_n$ denote the identity matrix of order $n$. 
 Assume that the matrix $\bf A$ has the following property over $\mathbb{F}_q$,
$
\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^T=\mathbf{I}_n.
$

We say $\mathbf{B}$ is a linear combination of the set
 $\{\mathbf{A},\mathbf{A}^T\}$, if
 $\mathbf{B}=\alpha_1\mathbf{A}+\alpha_2\mathbf{A}^T$
where $\alpha_i$ with $1\leq i \leq 2$ are elements in $\mathbb{F}_q$.

*My Question:*
How to find an $n\times n$ matrix $\mathbf{B}$  such that 
$\mathbf{B}\mathbf{B}^T=-\mathbf{I}_n$ over  $\mathbb{F}_q$ whithout restriction on $q$?

*Example:* Consider $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}_q$ such that $\alpha^2=-1$, then 
by considering $\mathbf{B}=\alpha\mathbf{A}$,  we get  $\mathbf{B}\mathbf{B}^T=-\mathbf{I}_n$.
But due to the condition over $\alpha$, we have $q \equiv1\pmod{4}$.

Comment: If $A^2=I$, then $A=A^{-1}$, and so there is no need to include $\alpha_3$.  However, your question doesn't actually make reference to $A$.  Do you need it to, i.e., do you require that $B$ is of the form $\alpha_1 A + \alpha_2 A^T$ for some $A$ satisfying $A^2=I$?

Comment: @Aaron You right. Based on your comment i edit the question.

Comment: @Aaron The condition $A=A^{-1}$ was not necessary and because of this I omitted it.

Comment: @egreg  I appreciate you for your nice edition.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't always possible.  For example, if $A=I$, then the problem collapses to $(\alpha A)(\alpha A)^T=\alpha^2 I=-I$, but $\alpha^2=-1$ does not always have solutions.

However, if $B=\alpha_1 A + \alpha_2 A^T$, then $BB^T=(\alpha_1^2+\alpha_2^2)I+\alpha_1 \alpha_2 (A^2+(A^T)^2)$.  If $\alpha^2=-1$ has no solutions in our field, then the only way we can hope to solve is if $A^2+(A^T)^2$ is a scalar.

Comment: "$A^2+(A^T)^2$ be a scalar" is an interesting note. Thanks.